# Paypal IPN: what if the buyer didn't click the return link after payment?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

From what I understand about integration with paypal - we rely on the IPN to process our the db injection like creating the order, recording the transaction into our db, etc.

In order to receive the IPN data from paypal requires the buyers to click the **return link** after his/ her payment.

But what if the buyer didn't click the **return link** after payment? The buyer will still see their cart with the items in it if they come straight back to our shopping site without clicking the **return link**, but they have already paid on paypal.

I can't think of any idea to solve this possibility that might happen, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to receive the IPN data from paypal requires the buyers to
>   click the return link after his/ her payment.

Your assumption is wrong, PayPal sends you the IPN as soon as the payment is made.

Comment: Hence why it's called "instant" payment notification. +1

Comment: oh great to know that I am wrong! but can I ask - how the paypal sends the IPN to my site? is it via the hidden field in the form that is sent to paypal - `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/mycart/paypal.php">`?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Indeed, you specify the URL that will process (and [send] verify) with the `notify_url` field.

Comment: thanks Alix. I have that hidden field of `notify_url` but paypal never the IPN to my localhost when I test it in my sandbox. Or do I need a live server?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Indeed you do, "localhost" as the name says is your *local* host, I have a localhost too. How would PayPal know which localhost you're referring to? You need to provide a host accessible from the outside, maybe configure your router and give PayPal your IP or use something like DynDNS (http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/), that way you (and PayPal) will be able to access your localhost with a URL that looks like "lauthiamkok.DynDNS.org".