# how to debug paypal IPN in development environment in visual studio

Tags: paypal

I am very new to paypal IPN.

I tried to find about how to test paypal IPN in developement environment. However could not get or not much help.

Does anyone can please help me about how to test papal IPN (or some sample code) about how to test it in development environment.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and include exactly what it is you want to test. "However could not get or not much help" isn't of much help to anyone, most of all yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few PayPal docs that should help you get started:

- [IPN Overview](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)
- [IPN Code Samples](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples)
- [Sandbox Testing/Accounts](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox)

The above links will help you begin testing IPN in a development (*sandbox*) environment.

Comment: also i found good concept on this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699976/paypal-ipn-what-if-the-buyer-didnt-click-the-return-link-after-payment